# Program doesn't stop after exception

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04. I use some exceptions in my program and when they are caught it gives me cout correctly. But the program continues to the end. Is there a way to stop the program after exception?

This is the code I am using:

```
try{
        if(BLER==-1) throw 12;
    }catch(int exception){
        cout << "ERROR: BLER value is invalid for x= " << x << ", BLER_input= " << BLER_input << ", m= "<< m << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just `return` early?

Comment: `catch` is designed to leave the program running after an exception was succesfully caught. You may just call `abort()` or `exit()` directly in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some solutions:

1. use `return` from your function (and do that accordingly to your return value) if you're doing this in the main() routine
2. use `exit(n)` where n is the exit code (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/)
3. `abort()` if that's a critical issue (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abort/)

Notice: as noted by James Kanze, `exit` and `abort` will **NOT** call the destructors of your local objects. This is worth noticing since you're dealing with classes.

Comment: I am using inside a class which is used from a main. I think exit(n) and abort would work better. thanks!!!

Comment: If you use exit, remember that if the exit code is 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS, it indicates success. Otherwise failure.

Comment: @DavidKernin That depends on the implementation.  `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` means success, `EXIT_FAILURE` means failure, and anything else is implementation defined.  (At least one common system requires the return code to be in the range 0...255.)

Comment: I suppose it's a well-established convention. It might be worth remembering that anything else is implementation defined and won't interfere with the rest. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidKernin It's a common convention, provided the value is in the range [0...255].  Under Posix, for example, returning 256 will be treated as success.  But you should be aware that it _is_ implementation defined, and be aware of your targeted implementations.

Comment: @DavidKernin You should probably point out that `exit(n)` and `abort` will _not_ call the destructors of local objects, so if you've got RAII classes holding resources that the system won't recover when your program exits (e.g. a temporary file), then those resources won't be released.  (I've occasionally used the convention of wrapping all of the code in `main` in a `try { ... } catch (int returnCode ) { return returnCode; }`, so that I could exit with an arbitrary return code by throwing it, and still be assured that local variables were destructed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can / must handle the problem in the current function, you can (and should) terminate right there:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

if ( BLER == -1 )
{
    std::cout << "BLER value is invalid." << std::endl;
    std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

*Exceptions* are meant to be thrown when you have an error condition, but no idea how to handle it properly. In this case you throw an *exception* instead of an integer, optionally giving an indication of the problem encountered in its constructor...

```
#include <stdexcept>

if ( BLER == -1 )
{
    throw std::runtime_exception( "BLER value is invalid" );
}
```

...and catch that *somewhere up the call tree*, where you can give a yet better error message, can handle the problem, re-throw, or terminate at your option). An exception only terminates the program by default if it is not caught at all ("unhandled exception"); that's the whole idea of the construct.

Throwing an integer and catching it in the same function is (ab-)using exceptions as in-function `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function exit: `exit(1);`, where 1 is the exit code (normally non-zero signals an error). You can use also `abort()` if you consider the exception as critical error.

Answer (score 0):

try using the return command like this

```
 return 0 //for successful termination or your preffered int status returned
 //or just
 return;
 //or (C++)
 [std::exit]
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop execution of a program after catching an exception, just call [`std::exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) in the `catch` block:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
try
{
  throw 42;
}
catch(int i)
{
  std::cout << "Caught int: " << i << ". Exiting...\n";
  std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf0a233abf57bb14).

This works outside of `main` as well. You can substitute `EXIT_FAILURE` with any `int` value you want, [portably in the `0-255` range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX).

Comment: Portably, maybe, but you won't necessarily get the results you expect.  (In the past, at least one common system treated all even values except 0 as failure.)

Comment: @James portably as in "Windows and POSIX". Which is a pretty inclusive definition. Other systems are so specific they're barely useful in a "portable" sense.

Comment: I don't know about that.  IBM mainframes are still widespread.  But it's true that most modern systems, while not necessarily Posix, do try to emulate the Unix interface to some degree.  (It's probably that most actual systems are embedded, and run neither Windows nor Unix, but most people aren't programming for such systems.)

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` handler in C++ allows one to handle the error outside the normal execution path for the code. Once handled, C++ assumes it is safe to resume normal operation or the program.

If this is not the case, say you just want to log the error, you are free to re`throw` the exception which causes to error to propagate further up the stack.

If the exception does not get caught at all, the C++ function `std::terminate` will get called. The default behavior is to call `abort`.

Is probably the best thing to do you your case is just rethrow the exeception by calling `throw` at the end of the catch block.