# Right way to organize and write exception classes

Tags: c++, exception

***My task was: basing on my project, create exception classes, that deliver from std::exception and implement virtual function what().***

Exceptions I possibly can get in my project simply can be caused during reading/writing files, converting/reading data types, creating different class members and so on. 
I tried to go this way:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#define MYEXCEPTION(exception_name) 
struct exception_name : public ::std::runtime_error  
{                                                   
typedef ::std::runtime_error                    
Base;                                      
explicit exception_name(const std::string& msg) 
    : Base(msg) {}                               
    explicit exception_name(const char* msg)        
    : Base(msg) {}                               
};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
class Catch: public std::exception
{
public:
    Catch() :exceptionCode(0), exceptionSource("no source"), exceptionMessage("no message") {SetError(my_ex);}
    explicit Catch(std::string message) :exceptionCode(0), exceptionSource("no source"), exceptionMessage(std::move(message)) { SetError(my_ex); }
    Catch(std::string source, std::string message) :exceptionCode(0), exceptionSource(std::move(source)), exceptionMessage(std::move(message)) { SetError(my_ex); }
    Catch(int code, std::string source, std::string message):exceptionCode(code), exceptionSource(std::move(source)), exceptionMessage(std::move(message)) { SetError(my_ex); }
    const char* what() const noexcept   {       return ((*error).c_str());  }

private:
    const std::string my_ex = ("CODE:" + std::to_string(exceptionCode) + "\n" + "SOURCE:" + exceptionSource + "\n" + "MESSAGE:" + exceptionMessage + "\n");
    void SetError(std::string ex) { error = &ex; }

    int exceptionCode;
    std::string exceptionSource;
    std::string exceptionMessage;

    std::string* error;
};

class ObjectException : public Catch {
public:
    ObjectException(char* message, int state): Catch(message) {     this->state = state;    }
    int GetState(void) { return state; }
private:
    int state;
};

class FileException : public std::exception {
    FileException(std::string destination, std::string path, std::string message): message(message.c_str()) {}
    const char* what() const throw() { return  "FileException occured\n"; }
private:
    std::string message;
    std::string destination;
};

class DataException : public std::exception {
public:
    DataException(char* message, int state) :exception(message) {
        this->state = state;
    }
    int GetState(void) { return state; }
    const char* what() const throw() { return  "DataException:invalid_type\n"; };
private:
    int state;  
};

class Exception : public std::exception
{
    std::string _msg;
public:
    Exception(const std::string& msg) : _msg(msg) {}

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return _msg.c_str();
    }
};
```

But, when I tried:

```
#include "catch.h"
void Polygon_m::Define() {

    std::ifstream input;
    input.open(path);
    if (input.is_open())
        std::cout << "Polygon_m::Defining_file:found" << std::endl;
    else
        throw  FileException("Polygon_m::Defining_file:", path , ":failed");
    ..........
}
```

*I have :
FileException::FileException(...)(declared in line...) is inaccessible*

Please give me some tips how to do it, I am trying to discover this topic for the whole week. It must be *very* simple.

I have already read many posts related to my question, but the problem is that I do not have a feeling of this topic. I couldn't find any book or an article that would explain me the details I need. If you know one, please give me a link.

Comment: Instead of deriving *directly* from `std::exception`, derive from `std::runtime_error`. It maintains an exception message for you.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this solution, to derive from std::runtime_error, many many times. But My task was to do it from std::exception

Comment: @M.Jane If this is homework, you might verify with the instructor. Any class derived from `runtime_error` is already derived from `exception`.

Comment: It is the first time i touch exceptions, I have no idea how to do it. Nobody explained it to me

Comment: My view, don't derive lots of your own exceptions, just use `std::runtime_error` for application level exceptions (or whatever is appropriate). Otherwise you lose some of the benefits of reducing your error handling by having to make new decisions (catch blocks) when the exception lands. (That doesn't help with this homework though)

Comment: Yes it is a home task, i can't ask an instructor, because it is a part of my studying. But anyway, question is still open, if anyone at least could give me a useful link... Again, I have to do derive it from std::exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `FileException::FileException` is inaccessible is that it was declared before any access specifier in the `class` block, and `class` defaults to `private` access.

Add `public` at the top of the class.

Also, `Catch` has a dependency problem between its members. `my_ex` is defined as an expression in terms of several subsequent members. But since members are initialized in declaration order, it will always read uninitialized values of `exceptionCode` etc. Try making `my_ex` a function instead.

Comment: i have a funny question: why after my try-catch block with an exception thrown  function continue to work?  Should i write inside exit(-1) myself?

Comment: Yes, I found, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781327/program-doesnt-stop-after-exception].